# How to image USB drives without having OS X mount them afterwards

Tags: usb, disk-utility

I am using OS X to write USB drives. I have a disk image and am using `dd` to the raw device to create the drive image. The problem I'm having is that OS X is automatically mounting the drives as soon as they are imaged. I'd like to prevent this behavior. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Are you using a scripted process and if yes it might be helpful to included the script in your question.  If the image has an UUID or if the volume label that is known and static you can probably set a `fstab` entry that should keep it from mounting.  I do this on drives that I have multiple partitions that I only want a given partition to mount when inserted, leaving other(s) not mounted.  May work for you however don't have enough info on how/what your doing to test it.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that on another question. It's a useful idea, although getting the UUID the first time is a bit of a pain.

Comment: I need a USB write blocker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download, install and start [Disk-Arbitrator](https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator/wiki/Downloads). Activate it in "block mount" mode.

Now execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/file of=/dev/diskN [operands]`. The resulting volume won't be mounted and no file will be created nor a folder will be changed:

```
sh-3.2# ls -laO
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  7 user      staff  -      306 17 Jan 22:21 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 8 root      admin  hidden 272 17 Jan 23:11 ..
drwx------  5 root      wheel  -      170 17 Jan 22:21 .Spotlight-V100
d-wx-wx-wt@ 2 root      wheel  hidden  68 17 Jan 22:21 .Trashes
drwx------  5 root      staff  -      170 17 Jan 22:21 .fseventsd
```

Original image content:

```
drwxrwxr-x  7 user      staff  -      306 17 Jan 22:21 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 9 root      admin  hidden 306 17 Jan 23:23 ..
drwx------  5 root      wheel  -      170 17 Jan 22:21 .Spotlight-V100
d-wx-wx-wt  2 root      wheel  hidden  68 17 Jan 22:21 .Trashes
drwx------  5 root      staff  -      170 17 Jan 22:21 .fseventsd
```

Don't forget to deactivate Disk Arbitrator after finishing the cloning.

---

My first proposal below modifies at least some metadata of the folders /Volumes/VolumeName/.Trashes and /Volumes/VolumeName/.fseventsd

Simply appending `&& diskutil eject /dev/diskN` after dd'ing should work:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/file of=/dev/diskN [operands] && diskutil eject /dev/diskN
```

Upon completion of the dd command this should immediately eject the thumb drive.

Comment: Does this cause the drive to be mounted, then unmounted, then ejected? My concern is that mounting the drive changes things on the drive.

Comment: @vy32 updated answer

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of Disk-Arbitrator. Thanks.